# Get Woocommerce Product Categories from Product variations in a WP_Query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

Hi I am trying to display product categories of the product variations. Below code works and shows product categories when I use `post_type=product` but displays nothing if I use the `post_type=product_variation`.

```
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
<?php

?>

                <li class="product">    

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span> 
                        <?php
                        $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $loop->post->ID  );
                        var_dump( $post_categories);
                          global $post;
                         // get categories
                          $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                          foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;

                          var_dump($cats_array);
                        ?>

                    </a>

                </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom post type set up called "product_variation"? In your functions.php or in a plugin?

Comment: @DerekNolan: Its default custom post type from Woocommerce:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/

Comment: From looking at that doc, product variations don't seem to have default taxonomies. Do you have some custom taxonomies set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce **Products Variations** don't handle any **custom taxonomy** as product categories, product tags or even normal Product attributes.

Instead you will need to get the parent Variable Product this way:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $loop->post->post_parent, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term )
    $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;

var_dump($cats_array);
```

You can even make it more compact and light using:

```
 $cats_array = wp_get_post_terms( $loop->post->post_parent, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "ids") );

var_dump($cats_array);
```

This time it will work for your Product Variations.

To make it work for both post_type "product" and "product_variation", you can use the following:

```
$the_id = $loop->post->post_parent > 0 ? $loop->post->post_parent : $loop->post->ID;

$cats_array = wp_get_post_terms( $the_id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "ids") );

var_dump($cats_array);
```

> If you have the `WC_Product` object instance from a Product variation, you can also get the parent variable product ID using [`WC_Product` `get_parent_id()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_parent_id)

To finish, in your code, this line **is wrong** and can be removed:

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $loop->post->ID  );
```

As `wp_get_post_categories()` function is made to get Category terms for normal WordPress Blog post, but not for Product category custom taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks Loic. You are a life safer :-)